# Add input fields with JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create an input field dynamically, using JQuery. It works up to a point but then absolutely stops working, no error in console and I am confused, please help.

I will attach a snippet alongside the code so you can better understand what's happening.

I can't define the problem because I don't fully understand what's happening, but I can try:

When I create a color I also want to create a size under that color, it works for the first color but doesn't work for other colors. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add-color").click(function() {
    $("#color-input-house")
      .html($("#color-input-house")
        .html() + '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control colors" placeholder="Color">' +
        ' <button type="button"  class="add-size small btn btn-primary rounded form-control">Add Size</button>' +
        ' <button type="button"  class="remove-size small btn btn-warning rounded form-control">Remove Size</button>' +
        ' <div class="size-input-house"></div></div>');
  });
  $("#remove-color").click(function() {
    if ($(".colors").length !== 1) {
      $(".add-size").last().remove();
      $(".remove-size").last().remove();
      $(".colors").last().remove();
    }
  });
  $(".add-size").click(function() {
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .find(".size-input-house")
      .html($(".size-input-house")
        .html() + '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control sizes" placeholder="Size"></div>');
  });
  $(".remove-size").click(function() {
    if ($(".sizes").length !== 1) {
      $(".sizes").last().remove();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control colors" placeholder="Color">
  <button type="button" class="add-size small btn btn-primary rounded form-control">Add Size</button>
  <button type="button" class="remove-size small btn btn-warning rounded form-control">Remove Size</button>
  <div class="size-input-house"></div>
</div>
<div id="color-input-house"></div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div>
    <button type="button" id="add-color" class="small btn btn-primary rounded form-control">Add Color</button>
    <button type="button" id="remove-color" class="btn btn-warning rounded form-control">Remove Color</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you add something with jquery and you want to apply click on them it is better to use following format in jquery:

```
$(document).on("click",".add-size",function(){
    $(this)
        .parent()
        .find(".size-input-house")
        .html($(".size-input-house")
            .html()+'<div class="form-group">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control sizes" placeholder="Size"></div>');
});
```

and the same way for another:

```
   $(document).on("click",".remove-size",function(){
        if($(".sizes").length !== 1){
            $(".sizes").last().remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay, noted sir

Comment: lol It worked, that was fast. I wish I could be better at this. Thanks a lot Sir

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution and a working code:

```
 $(document).on("click","#add-color",function(){
        $("#color-input-house")
            .html($("#color-input-house")
                .html()+'<div class="form-group">' +
            '<input type="text" class="form-control colors" placeholder="Color">' +
            ' <button type="button"  class="add-size small btn btn-primary rounded form-control">Add Size</button>' +
            ' <button type="button"  class="remove-size small btn btn-warning rounded form-control">Remove Size</button>' +
            ' <div class="size-input-house"></div></div>');
    });

    $(document).on("click","#remove-color",function(){
        if($(".colors").length !== 1){
            $(".add-size").last().remove();
            $(".remove-size").last().remove();
            $(".colors").last().remove();
        }
    });
    $(document).on("click",".add-size",function(){
        $(this)
            .parent()
            .find(".size-input-house")
            .html($(this)
                .parent()
                .find(".size-input-house")
                .html()+'<div class="form-group">' +
            '<input type="text" class="form-control sizes" placeholder="Size"></div>');
    });
    $(document).on("click",".remove-size",function(){
        if($(".sizes").length !== 1){
            $(".sizes").last().remove();
        }
    });
```

Notice the `$(document).on("click","#add-color",function(){` changes throughout the code. Thanks to the genius who gave an answer above.